# Sitecore search facets and Computed Fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-lucene

I have 10 article content items and each article item has a contributors checklist

[image]

I have created a Contributors Facet for faceted search in the editor. But checklist values are indexed as string id's.

[image]

Now on search result page the facet values are appearing as string id's.
I have created a ComputedField to index the display name

```
public class Contributors : IComputedIndexField
{
    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        var item = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

        if (item == null || item.Item == null) return string.Empty;

        StringBuilder ContributorsNameList = new StringBuilder();
        IIndexableDataField cField = indexable.GetFieldByName("Contributors");
        if (cField != null)
        {

            var cList = cField.Value.ToString().Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

            foreach (var cId in cList)
            {

                var cItem = item.Item.Database.GetItem(new ID(cId));

                if (cItem != null)

                    ContributorsNameList.Append(cItem.Name.ToString());

            }

            return ContributorsNameList;

        }

        return null;

    }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string ReturnType { get; set; }
}
```

and config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
      <contentSearch>
        <configuration>
          <defaultIndexConfiguration>
            <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
              <field fieldName="tagsfacet" storageType="yes" indexType="untokenized">                                      Sandbox.SitecoreCustomizations.ComputedIndexFields.TagsFacet, Sandbox</field>
            </fields>
            <fields hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="tagsfacet" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED"                                                          vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"                                        settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                 <Analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer,                    Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>          
            </fields>
          </defaultIndexConfiguration>
        </configuration>
      </contentSearch>
    </sitecore>
  </configuration>
```

but now getting both the id's and names(occurring twice)
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint or add `Log.Info` to your code to debug what it returns? You don't need to add `tagsFacet` in both `AddComputedField` and `AddFieldByFieldName` sections. `AddComputedField` should be enough. Also did you check what's the value of `tagsFacet` field in Luke? I only see screenshot from what's inside `contributors` field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at `BucketConfiguration.ResolveFacetValueToFriendlyName`
in Sitecore.Buckets.config.

```
<!-- RESOLVE FACET VALUE TO FRIENDLY NAME
If you are storing a field in the index that is being faceted on, it may be stored as an ID. This Setting when set to true, will try and resolve this to the friendly item name instead.            
USAGE: In an environment with huge amounts of items (e.g. 1 Million), this will not scale properly. -->

<setting name="BucketConfiguration.ResolveFacetValueToFriendlyName" value="false"/>
```

Patch this value to true and it should work.

This way your ComputedField should become obsolete.

Comment: Now I am able to index the names but it is occurring twice both id's and names as well.

Comment: I have edited computed field class. Please have a review.

Comment: Check this: http://techitpro.com/sitecore-faceting-list-and-link-fields/  When using the setting I showed you, you don't need a computed field to do what you want.